# Yii2 how to add multiple link in params.php

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to add multiple link in params.php .
Is it possible to do so ?

Current view of my params in yii2 .

## Params.php

```
<?php 
return [

"api_link" => "http://example.com" ,
];

I want to add multiple link in it 
Ex: 
<?php

return[
"api_link" => "http://example.com" & "http://www.example.com"

];
```

Is it possible to do so ? I tried but unable to succeed on this attempt .

Any lead over this will really be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store in an array

```
<?php 
   return [
    "api_link" => [
        "http://example.com",
          "http://example.com",
      ]
  ];
 ....
```

and for accessing you must iterate over it

```
     $myaArray =  [
        "api_link" => [
            "http://example.com",
            "http://www.example.com",
        ]
    ];

    foreach( $myArray['api_link'] as $key =>$value){
      echo $value;
    }
```

or

```
   echo $myArray['api_link'][0];
```

Comment: is it possible to mention if i use http://example.com then it will fetch 

<?php 
   return [
    "api_link" => [
        "http://example.com"
      ]
  ];

or,

If i use http://www. example.com then it will call 

<?php 
   return [
    "api_link" => [
        "http://www. example.com"
      ]
  ];

Comment: i want to configure this params api_link in such a way that if someone use "example.com" then he can able to fetch <?php return [ "api_link" => [ "example.com"; ] ];    and if someone using "www.example.com"  then it will fetch <?php return [ "api_link" => [ "www . example.com"; ] ];  .

Comment: Now its throwing error of CORS as someone using example.com with host www .example.com .

Comment: This seems a new question ... you have asked  for multiple link in  param  .. and you have alredy at least 3 valid answer .. if you have others question  .. you should rate properly (mark as accepted ) one of the valid answer  and post the new question in a new post ..

Answer (score 3):

You can set array for each params :

```
<?php 
    return [
        "api_link" => [
            "http://example.com",
            "http://example.com",
        ]
    ];
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. but it throw an error saying PHP error "array to string conversion" where my api hits this api_link.

Comment: you must use in this way:
Yii::$app->params["api_link"][0]
and 
Yii::$app->params["api_link"][1]

Comment: but my problems lies there. I want it to fetch http://example.com or http://www.example.com when fetch from either of one url.

Comment: Is it possible to mention if i use example.com then it will fetch 
<?php return [ "api_link" => [ "example.com"; ] ]; 

or,
 If i use www. example.com then it will call
 <?php return [ "api_link" => [ "www. example.com" ] ];

Answer (score 1):

i don't understand what you want. But you can try by multidimensional array.

```
 $arrayname = array(
  'url1' => 'nokibrokes.com',
  'url2' => 'example.com'
);

return $arrayname;
```